# SSH-Agent can't open a connection to authentication agent?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

When I SSH into my firewall server, then attempt to ssh into another machine on the local network from there I get the following error:

> Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Is there a way that I can have the agent run correctly from within another SSH session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I addition to what txwikinger said, you can also just use the `-A` command line option when SSHing to your firewall.

Comment: This works, thanks. Do you know what the correct option is to make this a default in .ssh/config?

Comment: Add `ForwardAgent yes` to the .ssh/config for that Host to default to the -A flag

Comment: You can also try this "eval `ssh-agent`".

Answer (score 10):

Yes. you can enable agent-forwarding by adding

```
ForwardAgent Yes
```

in your ssh configuration file (either `~/.ssh/config` for user or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` system wide.

See also http://drupal.txwikinger.me.uk/content/configurations-ssh-make-some-things-more-convenient.

Alternatively, if ssh is called with the option `-A`, the agent forwarding is also enabled as pointed out in the other answer.

Comment: However, be aware of possible security issues with using SSH agent forwarding: http://unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html#sec  There's a reason why they are disabled by default, and they should only be enabled for trusted hosts/networks.

Comment: This is not a problem of enabling AgentForwarding. This is a problem of access to a private key via a unix socket.

Comment: that option doesn't seem to be supported for this version of ssh (10.04)

Comment: Sorry. I think I did some wrong pasting. I have corrected it. I use this with 10.04 and 10.10 without any problems.